# "that" vs "which"

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can we use 'that' or “which” to fill in the blank in this sentence?

> Arteries of the heart ________ are blocked by plaque can reduce the flow of blood to the heart possibly resulting in heart attack or death.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways to express.

1. Arteries of the heart blocked by plaque can reduce the flow of blood to the heart possibly resulting in heart attack or death.
2. Arteries of the heart which are blocked by plaque can reduce the flow of blood to the heart possibly resulting in heart attack or death.
3. Arteries of the heart that are blocked by plaque can reduce the flow of blood to the heart possibly resulting in heart attack or death.

It's `Attribute Clause`, indeed, *which* and *that* are not always replaceable, but here both of them are OK.

Comment: Although my medical experience runs only to bandaging a cut finger, I suspect that you are talking about **plaque** rather than **plague**. Although the spelling is similar, the symptoms are not!

Comment: @RonaldSole Although I don't have medical experience at all(even cannot bandage a cut finger!), I think you are right. I just only thought about the black ;) . I'll edit it, thank you!